# Using a function inside a recurrence table index

Tags: functions, recursion

I have a recurrence relation with a complicated index pattern.  However, even simple examples fail.  For example, consider

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n - Floor[Sqrt[n]]], a[0] == 1}, a, {n, 0, 10}]
```

This gives the error

```
"All arguments in position 1 of a[1+n]==a[n-Floor[Sqrt[n]]] should be in the form n + integer."
```

When I look at the type for `Floor[Sqrt[n]]`, Mathematica tells me it is an integer, but it doesn't seem to recognize `n-Floor[Sqrt[n]]` as an integer.  How can I use a function like `Floor` inside the indices for a recurrence table?

Comment: Isn't the answer just a[n]=1 for all n?

Comment: It might be for this one.  This is just an simple example to see the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use RecurrenceTable for this... just define it recursively:

```
a[n_] := a[n - 1 - Floor[Sqrt[n - 1]]];
a[0] = 1;
```

You can verify that for this particular recursion, a[n]=1 for any n you care to chose. To see why RecurrenceTable does not work, note that the help says: "The eqns can involve objects of the form a[n+i] where i is any fixed integer." In this case, i is an integer, but it is not fixed.

Comment: This is a classic example of something not working until I ask about it.  I did try what you suggested based on another answer, but I must have typed something wrong somewhere.  It worked this time.  

The question still remains about why it won't work within RecurrenceTable.

Comment: Looking at the help for RecurrenceTable, it says: "The eqns can involve objects of the form a[n+i] where i is any fixed integer." In your case, i is an integer, but it is not fixed.

Comment: @bills I'd include the contents of your last comment in your answer, as it seems very relevant to the original question as it had been posed.